# How could I go about saving a set of printer settings as an entirely different printer?

Tags: printing

At work, we just recently got a new printer that has a lot more advanced settings than our secretaries are used to. I was recently asked by my boss to set up a few custom printing profiles, so if they want a staple top left, instead of having to go into the printer settings and set it up, they could just select that profile. No Problem.

However, it is becoming obvious that they are unable to handle anything involving the print settings, so I was trying to figure out a way to set them up as separate printers in the printer selection, so they never have to enter into the print settings. If they wanted two staples on the side, there would be a printer that said "Two Side Staples".

I know this seems ridiculous, but as I said before, they simply cannot handle going into the print settings and selecting a profile. We've shown them multiple times. It just won't work. Any suggestions or just pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that will work. I duplicated the printer driver and assigned default printer settings to each driver and renamed them with the associating printer profile. Thanks to everyone that looked at my question. This seemed like the easiest solution.